# How to specify an icon to be associated with display of a CHM file?

Tags: .net, winforms, chm

In my main form I have this code:

```
        FormHelpLauncher formHelpLauncher = new FormHelpLauncher();
        formHelpLauncher.LaunchHelpFile(chmFilename);
```

The FormHelpLauncher code looks like this:

```
   public partial class FormHelpLauncher : Form
   {
      public FormHelpLauncher()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }


      public void LaunchHelpFile(string chmFilename)
      {
         System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, chmFilename, HelpNavigator.TableOfContents);
      }
   }
```

This instantiates (but does not display) a Forms class, and then launches a CHM help file. The idea behind using the not-displayed auxiliary Forms class is that it provides extra decoupling between the help window and my program's main window. In particular, it results in the help window being included in the Alt-Tab list, which is what I prefer.

Now my question: Is there any way I can specify the icon that will be shown by Alt-Tab for the help window? I've tried various things, but Alt-Tab is always displaying the white-sheet-of-paper-with-yellow-question-mark icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FindWindow to find your Help window, and then send it a WM_SETICON message.

- [Is there any way to change the taskbar icon of a browser in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356883/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-taskbar-icon-of-a-browser-in-windows)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/2e2ef019-56a7-4d02-bef6-76968407d784/

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work great. I think you originally said there might be a problem with Windows 7, but I'm running Windows 7 and it's working for me. I do have one question though. Is it maybe necessary to "pin" the icon object or do something to prevent it from being garbage collected, now that another window is referencing it by its handle?